# MD5 checksum doesn't match

Tags: 14.04, md5sum

I'd like to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit so i've downloaded it to my harddrive. I checked the MD5 checksum and it doesn't match. Mine is 119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd The checksum given is dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153.
I've downloaded the ISO image several times on different computers and even physically different locations and networks but the MD5 checksum I keep getting is the one I mentioned above.

Is it me or could the reference MD5 checksum be wrong?

Comment: You're probably fine. The latest hashes seem to be for 14.04 and not 14.04.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/MD5SUMS `119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd` is the MD5 checksum for the 14.04.1 64bit image (`ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`) so your image is fine.

`dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153` is for the older 14.04 image (`ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso`).

Comment: For cases where the MD5 doesn't match, what would be a good course of action?  Delete the bad image, then re-download the image and check the checksum again?